# Append a row above the last row in an excel file using powershell

Tags: excel, powershell

I have the following code which inserts a row below the row A1000 in my excel file. How could I modify this to insert a row above the last row (will be different each time).

```
$xlShiftDown = -4121
$File = Get-ChildItem C:\Test.xls
$XL = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$WB = $XL.Workbooks.Open($File.Fullname)
$XL.Visible = $true
$Sheet = $WB.Worksheets.Item('clients')
$objRange = $XL.Range("A1000").EntireRow
[void]$objRange.Insert($xlShiftDown)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Excel ComObject the WorkSheet will have a property called `UsedRange` that works nicely for things like this.

```
$objRange = $($Sheet.UsedRange.Rows)[-1]
```

That should get you the last row of your sheet.

I realized that's probably slow if you have a lot of data. You can instead use the .count property of the UsedRange.Rows, and then just grab that row on the sheet like this:

```
$objRange = $Sheet.Rows.Item($Sheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count)
```

Comment: Gives me an error: `Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC
At line:1 char:1
+ $objRange = $Sheet.UsedRange.Rows[-1]
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException`

Comment: Right, sorry, the ComObject doesn't like you referencing things that way. Updated the answer so it should work now.

Comment: `Cannot index into a null array.
At line:1 char:3
+ $($objRange = $Sheet.UsedRange.Rows)[-1]
+   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray`

Comment: Do you not have anything on the sheet?

Comment: I do. 1000+ rows filled with data.

Comment: I'm sorry, I put the `$(` in the wrong place (answer is updated). You have to make Excel iterate all of it's rows first, then PowerShell can index the array that is generated. Alternatively you could do `$Sheet.Rows.Item($Sheet.UsedRange.Rows.count)` to explicitly get the entire row of the last row. This is probably faster if you have a lot of data on the sheet. I'll update again.

Comment: `This won't work because it would move cells in a table on your worksheet.
At line:1 char:1
+ [void]$objRange.Insert($xlShiftDown)
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException`

Comment: Do you want to insert a row above the last row or not? You said nothing about not messing with tables. Do you want it after the last row?

Comment: Your alternative worked. I had to modify the position though. `$objRange = $Sheet.Rows.Item($Sheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count)[0]`